# Access C++ application from Node JS via Node FFI - Read some data as bytes and write it to a file

Tags: c++, node.js, node-ffi

I am writing a Node JS wrapper for C++ program using NODE-FFI. I don't have access to the C++ source and It's in the DLL form.

There is a method to read some data until it finished and write to a file.

This is how **existing C# wrapper** achieving this task by calling the DLL and writing to a file using streams.

```
FileStream sw = new FileStream(fileName.pdf, FileMode.Create);

/* appHandle, fileHandle, buffer are pointers in the C++ program*/
while(Wrapper.readVirtualFile(appHandle, fileHandle, buffer, 1000) > 0){

    /* get length of the data */
    int len = (int)Wrapper.getSize(buffer);

    /* read data to the byte array */
    byte[] data = Wrapper.getData(buffer).ReadBytes(len);

    sw.Write(data, 0, len);
}

sw.Close();
```

This is what the **ReadBytes** Method looks like.

```
public static byte[] ReadBytes(this IntPtr ptr, int len){

    byte[] array = new byte[len];

    Marshal.Copy(ptr, array, 0, len);

    return array;
}
```

This is the **NODE JS wrapper** code. It's already calling the DLL from NODE-FFI. It creates the file *but does not contain any data in the file*.

```
/* Create stream in NodeJS. I want the file in **pdf format** */
const wstream = fs.createWriteStream(fileName.pdf);

/* appHandle, fileHandle, buffer are pointers in the C++ program */
while(NodeWrapper.readVirtualFile(appHandle, fileHandle, buffer, 1000) > 0){

    /* get length of the data */
    const len = NodeWrapper.getSize(buffer);
    console.log('length:', len);

    /* get the memory address of the data */
    const dataPtr = NodeWrapper.getData(buffer);
    console.log('dataPtr:', dataPtr);

    /* I am using NodeJS ref module to read the data */
    const data = ref.readCString(dataPtr);
    console.log('data:', data);

    wstream.write(data);
}

wstream.end();
```

Using `ref.readCString` seems not correct to me. What are the possible solutions for this?

Node FFI - https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi

NodeJS ref module - https://github.com/TooTallNate/ref

**UPDATE**

I added logging to the NodeJs application. Logging results looks like this(only a sample since the log is quite long).

```
len:  1000

dataPtr: <Buffer@0x0000024F7E5F9420 0a 65 6e 64>

data: endobj 53 0 obj[638.9 638.9 958.3 958.3 319.4 351.4 575 575 575 
575 575 869.4 511.1 597.2 830.6 894.4 575 1041.7 1169.4 894.4 319.4 
350 602.8 958.3 575 958.3 894.4 319.4 447.2 447.2 575 894.4 319.4 
383.3 319.4 575 575 575 575 575 575 575 575 575 575 575 319.4 319.4 
350 894.4 543.1 543.1 894.4 869.4 818.1 830.6 881.9 755.6 723.6 904.2 
900 436.1 594.4 901.4 691.7 1091.7 900 863.9 786.1 863.9 862.5 638.9 
800 884.7 869.4 1188.9 869.4 869.4 702.8 319.4 602.8 319.4 575 319.4 
319.4 559 638.9 511.1 638.9 527.1 351.4 575 638.9 319.4 351.4 606.9 
319.4 958.3 638.9 575 638.9 606.9 473.6 453.6 447.2 638.9 606.9 830.6 
606.9 606.9]
endobj
54 0 obj
[583.3 555.6 555.6 833.3 833.3 277.8 305.6 500 500 500 500 500 750 
444.4 500 722.2 777.8 500 902.8 1013.9 777.8 277.8 277.8 500 833.3 500 
833.3 777.8 277.8 388.9 388.9 500 777.8 277.8 333.3 277.8 500 500 500 
500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 277.8 277.8 277.8 777.8 472.2 472.2 
777.8 750 708.3 722.2 763.9 680.6 652.8 784.7 750 361.1 513.9 777.8 
625 916.7 750


len:  1000

dataPtr: <Buffer@0x0000024F7E5F9420 20 37 37 37>

data:  777.8 680.6 777.8 736.1 555.6 722.2 750 750 1027.8 750 750 
611.1 
277.8 500 277.8 500 277.8 277.8 500 555.6 444.4 555.6 444.4 305.6 500 
555.6 277.8 305.6
527.8 277.8 833.3 555.6 500 555.6 527.8 391.7 394.4 388.9 555.6 527.8 
722.2 527.8 527.8 444.4 500 1000]
endobj
```

Comment: With the given information and without knowing the DLL it is not really possible to tell what is wrong. Why do you assume that `ref.readCString` is the problem? Are you sure the body of the while loop is executed at all? You need to add some logging and shows what the content of `len`, `dataPtr` and `data` is for each iteration of `while`

Comment: @t.niese Thank you. Yes It's hitting the while loop and give output. I added some logs in NodeJS code and updated the question with the log and the new code. 

As I know `ref.readCString` encode the output to `utf8` format. Is it okay with files?

Comment: To me the logs look fine, my guess is the object returned by `ref.readCString` is not a regular buffer and as of that can not directly be written using `wstream.write(data)`. So you probably need to check if ffi provides a functionality to convert it into a buffer.

Comment: Do you know any alternative to ref.readCString?

Comment: I don't know the `node-ffi` module at all. But I'm pretty sure that `ref.readCString` is the correct function to call, as you get output in the logs.